# Let G be a not complet connected graph. Show that G is k- connected iff any 2 vertices at distance 2 are connected by k internally disjoint paths.

Tags: graph-theory

How can I show this?
To prove the entire statement I need to break it into two smaller statements:

$\Rightarrow$ If $G$ is $k$-connected then any two vertices at distance two are connected by $k$ internally disjoint paths.
 I'm stuck in this one.

$\Leftarrow$ If any two vertices at distance two are connected by $k$ internally disjoint paths then $G$ is $k$-connected.

If $G$ contains $k$ internally disjoint paths between any two vertices at distance two then $|V(G)| > k$ and G cannot be separated by fewer than $k $ vertices; thus $G$ is $k$-connected.

Comment: What is the second statement?  There seems to be only one.

Comment: Because the "if and only if" I need to show that G is k-connected and I need to show that any 2 vertices at distance 2 are connected by k internally disjoint paths.

Comment: And which of those is the second one?  You need to add some more context to the problem.  What are your thoughts?  How far can you get?  Where are you stuck?  The question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.

Comment: To prove the entire statement I need to break it into two smaller statements:
=> If G is k-connected then any two vertices at distance two are connected by k internally disjoint paths.
 I'm stuck in this one.

<= If  any two vertices at distance two are connected by k internally disjoint paths then G is k-connected.
If G contains k internally disjoint paths between any two vertices at distance two then |V(G)| > k and G cannot be separated by fewer than k vertices; thus G is k-connected

Answer (score 1):

We will establish the harder direction:

> Claim 1: If $G$ is not $k$-connected then there is a pair of vertices $u,v$ of distance 2 such that there are no more than $k-1$ internally vertex-disjoint paths from $u$ to $v$.

Proof: Suppose that $G$ is not $k$-connected. Then let $S$ be a *minimum* cut-set of $G$ i.e., $S$ is a smallest set of vertices such that $G \setminus S$ has at least 2 components. Then letting $L_1,\ldots, L_c; c \ge 2$ be the components of $G \setminus S$ we note that every vertex in $S$ has a neighbour in $G$ in every one of $L_1,\ldots, L_c$. [Indeed suppose there is a vertex $u \in S$ that does not have a neighbour in $G$ in every one of $L_1,\ldots, L_c$. Then let us assume WLOG that $c$ is such that $u$ has no neighbour in $G$ in $L_c$. Then note that $L_c$ is a component of $G \setminus (S \setminus \{u\})$ [make sure you see why], which contradicts the assumption that $S$ is a minimum cut-set of $G$.]

So now fix any vertex $y \in S$ and let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be vertices adjacent to $y$ also satisfying $x_1 \in L_1$ and $x_2 \in L_2$. Then as $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in different compoenents of $G \setminus S$ it follws that there is no edge between  $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $G$, and as $x_1$ and $x_2$ have a common neighbour, it follws that the distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $G$ is precisely 2. However, the maximum number of internally vertex-disjoint paths between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is at most $|S| < k$. So Claim 1 follows.

So, Claim 1 establishes the harder direction. Can you do the other direction i.e., if $G$ is $k$-connected then for every pair of vertices $u,v$ s.t. $d_G(u,v)=2$, there are at least $k$ interally vertex-disjoint paths in $G$ from $u$ and $v$? There is a hint below.

> If there are not at least $k$ interally vertex-disjoint paths in $G$ from $u$ and $v$, then there is a cut-set $S$ that has fewer than $k$ vertices such that $u$ and $v$ are in different components of $G \setminus S$. What is the definition of $k$-connected again?

---

Meanwhile I read your original post more closely. What is the definition of $k$-connected again? You did NOT prove that $G$ is $k$-connected as that would require $k$ internally vertex-disjoint paths between **any two** vertices $u$ and $v$, not just pairs $u$ and $v$ where $u$ and $v$ are of distance 2 from each other in $G$.

Comment: I tried to prove the direction ⇐  If any two vertices at distance two are connected by k internally disjoint paths then G is k-connected by the following answer: "If G contains k internally disjoint paths between any two vertices at distance two then |V(G)|>k and G cannot be separated by fewer than k vertices; thus G is k-connected." But I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: You have to show *why* $G$ cannot be separated by fewer than $k$ vertices though. That is the crux of the proof. You need to provide a proof of this.The answer above gives this. i.e., it assumes that there is a set of fewer than $k$ vertices that separates the graph, and shows the existence of a pair of vertices $u=x_1,v=x_2$, such that $u$ and $v$ are of distance 2 apart but there are no more than $k-1$ internally disjoint paths between $u$ and $v$

Comment: oh...ok, I got it...the Claim 1 it's a complete proof for the direction "⇐ If any two vertices at distance two are connected by k internally disjoint paths then G is k-connected", correct? But I'm still stuck in the direction "⇒  If G is k-connected then any two vertices at distance two are connected by k internally disjoint paths", could you help me with this one?

Comment: The answer to that is in my answer above too.

Comment: Meanwhile what is the definition of $k$-connected again.